# Node.JS Socket.IO application client identification issue. All clients appear with same id as last connected client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Im trying to build a simple system where i attach certain details to clients such as nickname, country etc, but i have stumbled upon a issue regarding information not being registered correctly.

Please take a look at my code:

#### index.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),

    glob = require('glob'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),

    satelize = require('satelize');

var chat = require(__dirname + '/inc/chat');

server.listen(8888);

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    chat.init(satelize,socket, function () {
        var client = chat.fetchClient(socket.id);
        socket.emit('client info', client);
        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log('Message recieved from ' + client.id);
            socket.emit('client info', client);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            chat.removeClient(client);
        });
    });
});
```

#### /inc/chat.js

```
module.exports = {

    /* client object initialization */
    client : {
        id          : null,
        username    : null,
        geo         : null
    },

    /* client array initialization */
    clients: [],

    init: function (satelize, socket, callback) {
        var init = this;
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
            var client = this.client;
            client.id = socket.id;
            satelize.satelize( { ip : this.ip(socket ) }, function(error, payload) {
                client.geo = payload;
                init.addClient(client);
                callback();
            });
        }
    },

    /* information retrieval*/
    ip: function (socket) {
        return cleanIp(socket.handshake.address)
    },

    /* client (the user) stuff */
    addClient: function (client) {
        if (client.id !== null) {
            this.clients.push(client);
            console.log(client.id + ' added to clients.');  
        } else {
            console.log('Cannot add client: id (null)');
        }
    },
    fetchClient: function (id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
            if(this.clients[i].id == id) {
                return this.clients[i];
            }
        }
    },
    removeClient: function (client) {
        console.log('removing client: ');
        console.log(client.id);
        var found = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
            if (this.clients[i] == client) {
                this.clients.splice(i,1);
                found = this.clients[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this.clients.length > 0) {
            console.log('client list after removal: ');
            for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
                console.log(this.clients[i].id);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('No clients in client array.');
        }
    }
}

function cleanIp (ip) {
    return ip.replace('::ffff:','');
}
```

in index.html i have the following js for visual representation of id and messaging:

```
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('client info', function (data) {
        $('.client-id').text(data.id);
    });

    $('#input').keydown(function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) {
            if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                socket.emit('message', $(this).val());
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }
    });
```

Ok so if i start this simple node server and open the page in three different browser tabs without sending any message, the id's seems to be correct.

[image: Three browser tabs in Google Chrome with the application running. Displaying unique udentifiers]

But as soon as i send a message from one of the browser tabs it adopts the last connected clients id.

[image: Three browser tabs in Google Chrome with the application running. Displaying the same udentifiers as the last connected client]

When the server starts it outputs the following in the console:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
/#h9sraEo5c8uLKgczAAAA added to clients.
/#opAfZCrRa64gFsR7AAAB added to clients.
/#x-WfhClfNsLEWE85AAAC added to clients.
```

If i refresh the first tab:

```
removing client:
/#x-WfhClfNsLEWE85AAAC
client list after removal:
/#x-WfhClfNsLEWE85AAAC
/#x-WfhClfNsLEWE85AAAC
/#pdlKD-v3K15_2voZAAAD added to clients.
```

And if i send a message from that tab:

```
Message recieved from /#pdlKD-v3K15_2voZAAAD
```

If i now switch to another tab and write a message the server outputs the same message as above, and changes the visual representation of the id in the browser.

Why does the id's of the connected clients change to the id of the last connected client?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the client object starting on `line 4, chat.js` is being reused without detalis being reset resulting in data not being unique.

After removing the object and rather generating it on the fly starting at `line 16, chat.js` solved all known problems regarding all id's being the last one.

Here are the updated scripts:

#### index.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),

    glob = require('glob'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),

    satelize = require('satelize');

var chat = require(__dirname + '/inc/chat');

server.listen(8888);

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.id = chat.uniqueId();
    chat.init(satelize,socket, function () {
        var client = chat.fetchClient(socket.id);
        socket.emit('client info', client);
        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
            console.log(client.id + ' sent: ' + msg);
            socket.emit('client info', client);
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            chat.removeClient(client);
        });
    });
});
```

#### chat.js

```
module.exports = {

    /* client array initialization */
    clients: [],

    init: function (satelize, socket, callback) {
        var init = this;
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
            var client = {
                id : null,
                username: null,
                geo : null
            }
            client.id = socket.id;
            satelize.satelize( { ip : this.ip(socket ) }, function(error, payload) {
                client.geo = payload;
                var exists = null;
                if (init.clients.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < init.clients.length; i++) {
                        if(init.clients[i].id == client.id) {
                            exists = client.id;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (exists == null) {
                    init.addClient(client); 
                }
                callback();
            });
        }
    },

    /* information retrieval*/
    ip: function (socket) {
        return cleanIp(socket.handshake.address)
    },

    /* client (the user) stuff */
    addClient: function (client) {
        if (client.id !== null) {
            this.clients.push(client);
            console.log(client.id + ' added to clients.');  
        } else {
            console.log('Cannot add client: id (null)');
        }
    },
    fetchClient: function (id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
            if(this.clients[i].id == id) {
                return this.clients[i];
            }
        }
    },
    removeClient: function (client) {
        console.log('removing client: ' + client.id);
        var found = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
            if (this.clients[i] == client) {
                this.clients.splice(i,1);
                found = this.clients[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (this.clients.length > 0) {
            console.log('client list after removal: ');
            for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
                console.log(this.clients[i].id);
            }
        } else {
            console.log('No clients in client array after last removal.');
        }
    },

    uniqueId : function() {
        function s4() {
            return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
        }
        return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4();
    }

}

function cleanIp (ip) {
    return ip.replace('::ffff:','');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I your `socket.on('message')` event in **index.js**, you get `msg` from the callback, but you are using `client` which has the current client.
Instead use `msg` variable like:

```
   socket.on('message', function (msg) { 
        //msg holds the client
        console.log('Message recieved from ' + msg.clientId);
        socket.emit('client info', client);
    });
```

And send the clientId from the client like:

```
var id = socket.socket.sessionid;
socket.emit('message', {message: $(this).val(), clientId: id);
```

**NOTE:** this sessionid is not the same as the server clientid.

Comment: The argument holds the actual message sent from the client which can be whatever, in this case a string from a input element. I do not want the server use and id passed from the client since that way the system can be manipulated. Therefore, by using the actual socket, i can look up the clients details in an array server side by its id. At least that was my plan, but something is not right apparently. Thanks for looking at it tho, but this is wrong.

Comment: Sorry. The `msg` message it self has `clientid` property. Check the answer again.

Comment: I had to check to be sure, the msg variable only holds the value from the `#input`. Please see: `socket.emit( 'message', $(this).val() );` If i console.log the msg variable server side it only holds a string representing the `#input` elements value.